# c# consume http body without waiting end of stream/body

Tags: java, c#, http, streaming, chunked

I am a Java developer

I'm trying to stream an unknown amount of binary data from client to server over http put request. 
For some reason, my server is written in c# (.net core) and for convenience, my client (that i use only for test) is written in java.

As i'm waiting for unknown amount of data and in order to test my server rest api, my java client open a binary file and send binary packet over http put request (160 bytes by packet for example).
When i begin streaming data from client, i'm not able to consume the body (http stream) in server side until the client finished to send all binary packets.

http headers in use use: Connection-KeepAlive, Content-Type=> application/octetstream, transfer-encoding => chunked

So, I would like to consume the body without waiting the entire body.

Any hint of how to perform it ?

I'm thinking about removing await operator before async method that consume body and wait until client abort or close the connection in server side but i don't  know if this is a good idea.

Below some piece of related code:

- server side written in c#

```
[HttpPut]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SendData(string id, string device, string token){
            ...
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()){
                await HttpContext.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(ms);
            }
            ...
            //do stuff
        }
```

- java client

  ```
  HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(
            "http://localhost:8080/test"
            ).openConnection();

    byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(FILE_TO_SEND_PATH));
    ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);

    conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(160);
    //conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(is.available());
    conn.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.connect();

    OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
    //InputStream i = conn.getInputStream();

    byte[] bytes = new byte[160];
    int read = 0;
    while ((read = is.read(bytes)) > 0) {
         out.write(bytes, 0, read);
         System.out.println(read);
         TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.sleep(125 * read);
         out.flush();
    }
    out.close();
  ```